# Using postgres table description

Tags: postgresql

In postgres while listing the relation with \dt+ new columns 'size' and 'Description' column are added. As the name suggests Description can we use to store the description of the table, if yes how?

```
# \dt
        List of relations
 Schema |  Name   | Type  | Owner 
--------+---------+-------+-------
 drs    | Records | table | rho
 drs    | Reports | table | rho
(2 rows)

# \dt+
                      List of relations
 Schema |  Name   | Type  | Owner |    Size    | Description 
--------+---------+-------+-------+------------+-------------
 drs    | Records | table | rho   | 8192 bytes | 
 drs    | Reports | table | rho   | 0 bytes    | 
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be defined using the [`comment`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) statement:

```
comment on table drs."Reports" is 'This table stores reports';
```